# ResultSet returns nothing

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I have a problem about the output of the servlet. It seems that it outputs nothing. Im using Apache Tomcat 8.0.43. It does not return any exceptions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
This is the form in my html file.

```html
<form action="servlet1" method="POST">
<p>Email<br>
  <input type="text" name="email" required>
</p>
<p>Password<br>
  <input type="text" name="password" required>
</p>
<p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
```

This is servlet1 which process the inputs and dispatches to another servlet(servlet2) to check if the the following inputs exist in the database.

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
    throws ServletException, IOException {  

    response.setContentType("text/html");  
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

    String email = request.getParameter("email");  
    String password = request.getParameter("password");  

    if (Login.validate(email, password)) {  
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("servlet2");  
        rd.forward(request,response);  
    }  
    else {  
        out.print("Sorry username or password error");  
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");  
        rd.include(request,response);  
    }           
    out.close();  
}
```

Then I got this Login class having a method that checks if user exist in the database. I think this is where the problem is.

```
public static boolean validate(String email,String password){  
    boolean status=false;  
    try {  
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String conStr = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/virtuoso?user=root&password=";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(conStr); 

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM tutor WHERE email=? and password=?";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);  
        ps.setString(1,email);  
        ps.setString(2,password);  

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();  
        status = rs.next();  
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        //empty
    }  
    return status;  
}
```

Comment: Don't silently swallow Exception(s). You have no way of telling what the error is because of that.

Comment: What is written in `servlet2` file?

Answer (score 0):

use try catch and know the exception. without it you will not know the issue.

```
try{

.

.

} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This post doesn't answer the question while the OP asking _"ResultSet returns nothing"_ this should be the comment.

Answer (score 0):

ResultSet next may returns `false` when it is below the last row. Refer the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--). It depends on the jdbc driver vendor to return either false or Exception. Please check your driver vendor specs.

Comment: That's not true. `A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the current row, and so on. `